# How do I isolate $S$ in $P = \overline S - RSR^{\mathsf H}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have

\begin{align}
R &= U^{\mathsf H}S^{-1} \\
P &= \overline{S} - RU
\end{align}

I know $R$ and $P$.  $P$ and $S$ are Hermitian and invertible.  $U$ is symmetric.  How do I find $S$ and $U$?

I got halfway:

\begin{align}
R &= U^{\mathsf H}S^{-1} \\
&\Downarrow \\
U &= (RS)^{\mathsf H} \\
&= S^{\mathsf H}R^{\mathsf H} \\
&= SR^{\mathsf H}
\end{align}
since $S$ is Hermitian.  Then,
\begin{align}
P &= \overline S - RSR^{\mathsf H}
\end{align}

I don't see how to isolate $S$ here.

---

Notation: $R^{\mathsf H}$ denotes the Hermitian of $R$ (the conjugate transpose) and $\overline S$ denotes the conjugate of $S$.

---

My motivation is that I would like to fill in my table:

[image: The complex multivariate normal distribution]

So what I really need are $S$, $U$ in terms of $H$, $J$.

Comment: If $Id-\overline{R}R$ is invertible, then $(Id-\overline{R}R)^{-1}\overline{R} P=U$ and $(Id-\overline{R}R)^{-1}\overline{P}=S$.

Comment: @san I'm not sure how your comment differs from the answer here, but would you mind adding an answer?

Comment: @san Also, if it's right, of course you'll get the bounty, but it would be instructive if you wouldn't mind sharing how you solved it.

Comment: @NeilG san is right. Since $U$ is complex symmetric, $U^H=\overline{U}$. Take complex conjugate of both sides of $P=\overline{S}-RU$ and substitute $\overline{U}=U^H=RS$ into it, you get $\overline{P}=S-\overline{R}RS$ and hence $S=(I-\overline{R}R)^{-1}\overline{P}$. Now you may obtain $U$ from $\overline{U}=U^H=RS$.

Comment: @user1551 That makes perfect sense, thank you.  I've updated my chart in the question.  I'm working on the final term $\mathbf \mu$ in terms of $\mathbf\eta, H, J$.  Any ideas?  I can ask another question if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Id−\overline{R}R$ is invertible, then $(Id−\overline{R}R)^{−1}\overline{R}P=U$ and $(Id−\overline{R}R)^{−1}\overline{P}=S$.  In fact, since $U$ is symmetric, $\overline{U}=U^H=RS$ and so, from $P=\overline{S}-RU$ we obtain 
$$
\overline{P}=S-\overline{R}\overline{U}=S-\overline{R}RS=(Id-\overline{R}R)S,
$$
and so $(Id−\overline{R}R)^{−1}\overline{P}=S$. On the other hand $\overline{R}\overline{S}=U$, and so,
from  $P=\overline{S}-RU$ we obtain
$$
\overline{R}P=\overline{R}\overline{S}-\overline{R}RU=U-\overline{R}RU=(Id-\overline{R}R)U,
$$
and so $(Id−\overline{R}R)^{−1}\overline{R}P=U$.

Comment: Thanks, this looks right, and I've tested this and it works.  Looks like I made a math error in my calculations in the question :)